# How to write the following code more efficiently?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

Any efficient way to write the following loop? dataPLprocessed is a time-series data and I want to calculate the score based on rolling 7 days percentile value (see the loop below for more explanation).

```
dataPLprocessed['percentile'] = dataPLprocessed['lineardifference'].rolling('7D').apply(lambda x: x.rank(pct=True).values[
                    -1])
dataPLprocessed['score'] =np.NaN
dataPLprocessed.index = range(len(dataPLprocessed))
# print(dataPLprocessed)
for i in range(len(dataPLprocessed)):
    if (dataPLprocessed['percentile'][i] < .05) | (
            dataPLprocessed['percentile'][i] > .95):
        dataPLprocessed.loc[i, 'score'] = 10
    elif (dataPLprocessed['percentile'][i] < .1) | (
            dataPLprocessed['percentile'][i] > .9):
        dataPLprocessed.loc[i, 'score'] = 9
    elif (dataPLprocessed['percentile'][i] < .15) |(
            dataPLprocessed['percentile'][i] > .85):
        dataPLprocessed.loc[i, 'score'] = 8
    elif (dataPLprocessed['percentile'][i] < .2) |(
            dataPLprocessed['percentile'][i] > .8):
        dataPLprocessed.loc[i, 'score'] = 7
    elif (dataPLprocessed['percentile'][i] < .25) |(
            dataPLprocessed['percentile'][i] > .75):
        dataPLprocessed.loc[i, 'score'] = 6
    elif (dataPLprocessed['percentile'][i] < .3) |(
            dataPLprocessed['percentile'][i] > .7):
        dataPLprocessed.loc[i, 'score'] = 5
    elif (dataPLprocessed['percentile'][i] < .35) |(
            dataPLprocessed['percentile'][i] > .65):
        dataPLprocessed.loc[i, 'score'] = 4
    elif (dataPLprocessed['percentile'][i] < .4) |(
            dataPLprocessed['percentile'][i] > .6):
        dataPLprocessed.loc[i, 'score'] = 3
    elif (dataPLprocessed['percentile'][i] < .45) |(
            dataPLprocessed['percentile'][i] > .55):
        dataPLprocessed.loc[i, 'score'] = 2
    elif (dataPLprocessed['percentile'][i] < .5) |(
            dataPLprocessed['percentile'][i] > .5):
        dataPLprocessed.loc[i, 'score'] = 1
```

The dataframe (converted into a dictionary) is given below:

```
{Timestamp('2020-05-17 23:30:00'): -0.18600000000000005, Timestamp('2020-05-17 23:45:00'): -0.18600000000000005, Timestamp('2020-05-18 00:00:00'): -0.18600000000000005, Timestamp('2020-05-18 00:15:00'): -0.18900000000000008, Timestamp('2020-05-18 00:30:00'): -0.18800000000000008, Timestamp('2020-05-18 00:45:00'): -0.18900000000000008, Timestamp('2020-05-18 01:00:00'): -0.18600000000000005, Timestamp('2020-05-18 01:15:00'): -0.18300000000000005, Timestamp('2020-05-18 01:30:00'): -0.18200000000000005, Timestamp('2020-05-18 01:45:00'): -0.18400000000000005, Timestamp('2020-05-18 02:00:00'): -0.18400000000000005, Timestamp('2020-05-18 02:15:00'): -0.18300000000000005, Timestamp('2020-05-18 02:30:00'): -0.18200000000000005, Timestamp('2020-05-18 02:45:00'): -0.18600000000000005, Timestamp('2020-05-18 03:00:00'): -0.18700000000000008, Timestamp('2020-05-18 03:15:00'): -0.19000000000000009, Timestamp('2020-05-18 03:30:00'): -0.18999999999999995, Timestamp('2020-05-18 03:45:00'): -0.18999999999999995, Timestamp('2020-05-18 04:00:00'): -0.18999999999999995, Timestamp('2020-05-18 04:30:00'): -0.18700000000000008}
{Timestamp('2020-05-17 23:30:00'): -0.18600000000000005, Timestamp('2020-05-17 23:45:00'): -0.18600000000000005, Timestamp('2020-05-18 00:00:00'): -0.18600000000000005, Timestamp('2020-05-18 00:15:00'): -0.18900000000000008, Timestamp('2020-05-18 00:30:00'): -0.18800000000000008, Timestamp('2020-05-18 00:45:00'): -0.18900000000000008, Timestamp('2020-05-18 01:00:00'): -0.18600000000000005, Timestamp('2020-05-18 01:15:00'): -0.18300000000000005, Timestamp('2020-05-18 01:30:00'): -0.18200000000000005, Timestamp('2020-05-18 01:45:00'): -0.18400000000000005, Timestamp('2020-05-18 02:00:00'): -0.18400000000000005, Timestamp('2020-05-18 02:15:00'): -0.18300000000000005, Timestamp('2020-05-18 02:30:00'): -0.18200000000000005, Timestamp('2020-05-18 02:45:00'): -0.18600000000000005, Timestamp('2020-05-18 03:00:00'): -0.18700000000000008, Timestamp('2020-05-18 03:15:00'): -0.19000000000000009, Timestamp('2020-05-18 03:30:00'): -0.18999999999999995, Timestamp('2020-05-18 03:45:00'): -0.18999999999999995, Timestamp('2020-05-18 04:00:00'): -0.18999999999999995, Timestamp('2020-05-18 04:30:00'): -0.18700000000000008}
```

Comment: You can start by using an interim variable assigned to `dataPLprocessed['percentile'][i]` each iteration, so that way you're not re-accessing the same element potentially up to 20 times per iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility would be to generate the percentiles dynamically, and check for the complement, e.g., `x not between 0.05 and 0.95`:

```py
for i in range(len(dataPLprocessed)):
    x = dataPLprocessed['percentile'][i]
    for k in range(10):
        p = round(0.05 + 0.05 * k, 2)
        if not (p < x < 1 - p):
            dataPLprocessed.loc[i, 'score'] = 10 - k
            break
```

Comment: You're welcome @UmangGarg. Fair warning, I didn't test this code.

Comment: is there a need to use round here?

Comment: It's not *super* necessary, no. But generating the percentiles with that equation *does* introduce floating point arithmetic error, e.g.: `0.05 + 0.05 * 6 = 0.35000000000000003`.

Answer (score 1):

instead of using `dataPLprocessed['percentile'][i]` in each if statement you can assign it to a variable.

```
for i in range(len(dataPLprocessed)):
    x = dataPLprocessed['percentile'][i]

    if (x < .05) | ( x > .95):
        dataPLprocessed.loc[i, 'score'] = 10
    elif (x < .1) | ( x > .9):
        dataPLprocessed.loc[i, 'score'] = 9
    elif (x < .15) |( x > .85):
        dataPLprocessed.loc[i, 'score'] = 8
    elif (x < .2) |(x > .8):
        dataPLprocessed.loc[i, 'score'] = 7
    elif (x < .25) |( x > .75):
        dataPLprocessed.loc[i, 'score'] = 6
    elif (x < .3) |(x > .7):
        dataPLprocessed.loc[i, 'score'] = 5
    elif (x < .35) |( x > .65):
        dataPLprocessed.loc[i, 'score'] = 4
    elif (x < .4) |( x > .6):
        dataPLprocessed.loc[i, 'score'] = 3
    elif (x < .45) |( x > .55):
        dataPLprocessed.loc[i, 'score'] = 2
    elif (x < .5) |( x > .5):
        dataPLprocessed.loc[i, 'score'] = 1
```